# Webdis returning empty response

Tags: redis, webdis

I installed webdis and I have Redis server running. When I try to set/get a key through webdis , the response is empty though. So when I do:

```
curl http://127.0.0.1:7379/SET/hello/world
```

I don't get any response.

I am not sure how to debug this, so my question is: Why would the response be empty, and how can I debug webdis?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I would debug:

1. Make sure Redis is available by running the equivalent command using Redis client:

   `redis-cli set hello world`

   This should respond with an "OK" response.
2. Use the "-v" option with curl to see the HTTP response.

   `curl -v http://127.0.0.1:7379/SET/hello/world`

   This should respond with the details of the request and response.

   In the response, you should see something like:

   `< HTTP/1.1 200 OK`
   if Webdis got a valid response from Redis.

   `< HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable`
   if Webdis got no response from Redis

In some cases (on Ubuntu), I have seen Webdis simply stop responding.  In the example above, curl would simply not respond.  In that case, I just kill and restart the webdis process. Haven't yet figured out a fix for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following :

- Use [MONITOR](http://redis.io/commands/MONITOR) command to check what's happening at Redis server end .
- Set the verbosity for logging in Webdis :  Note that webdis doesn't immediately log messages at startup. Try setting a verbosity to 4 and running curl `http://localhost:7379/PING` and tail the log file, you should see two lines printed.(https://github.com/nicolasff/webdis/issues/65)

Hope that Helps !